# Wrong data types python

Tags: python

Hi and thanks for your time. I need to add the wrong data types in my code that says that it should be an invalid operation when I am using strings. I try to add the break statement in for loop, but I cannot go through. I hope you can help me.

Code:

```
 def userInput():
    upper = int(input("Enter UppperNumber from column: "))
    if upper < 0:
        print(upper,"Nice, it is in range")
    elif upper < 256:
        print(upper, "Nice, it is in range")
    else:
        print(
            "You must use only numbers which range is : 0 - 255")
        upper = None# we define upperbit as nothing and restart the function, same applies with lowerbot
        userInput()

    lower = int(input("Enter LowerNumber from column: "))
    if lower < 0:
        print(lower, "Nice, it is in range")
    elif lower < 256:
        print(lower, "Nice, it  is in range")
    else:
        print(
            "You must use only numbers which range is : 0 - 255")
        lower_bit_int = None
        userInput()
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code. Also include input (if you can't hardcode it), output and expected output. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an try except statement to your input and maby instead of recursivly calling your function do it in a while statement. Example:

```
def userInput():
    while True:
        upper = None
        try:
            upper = int(input("Enter UppperNumber from column: "))
            if 0 < upper < 256:
                print(upper, "Nice, it is in range")
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("You must use only numbers which range is : 0 - 255")
```